# Why is this NSMenuItem getting disabled when the window loses focus?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsmenu

I am programmatically creating an `NSMenu` with a `NSMenuItem`. When the window of the application is active, the `NSMenuItem` is enabled:

[image: Enabled NSMenuItem]

However, as soon as the window loses focus the menu item becomes disabled:

[image: Disabled NSMenuItem]

Here's how I am creating the `NSMenu`:

```
- (void)_quit
{
  [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];
}

- (NSMenu *)_setupMenu
{
  NSMenu *statusMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Demo"];
  NSMenuItem *quit = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit" action:@selector(_quit) keyEquivalent:@""];

  [statusMenu addItem:quit];

  return statusMenu;
}
```

What is causing this issue? And how do I go about making it enabled regardless of whether the application is in focus or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because menu items are enabled based on the responder chain.

In your case, you can use the `terminate:` selector instead of your own.
As this is declared in the `NSApplication` class, which is also part of the responder chain, the item will then be always active.

```
NSMenuItem *quit = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@""];
```

More on this here: [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html)

Comment: And the application delegate is right after `NSApp` in the chain if you need to run your own code for this menu item.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: How should I modify the delegate to make this work on my own code?

Comment: Implement a method with the same name as the action selector in the app delegate and make sure there's no other method with that name anywhere else in the responder chain, @aam1r.