# NSMenuItem's not selectable after opening window

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmenu

I'm having an issue very similar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767649/why-is-this-nsmenuitem-getting-disabled-when-the-window-loses-focus).

I am programatically creating a NSMenu and adding my items. One selection of an item it shows a window. This works as intended. However, when I close the window I can no longer select any of the options in the menu.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)createMenu {
      NSMenu *statusMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];

      NSMenuItem *historyItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"History" action:@selector(onHistory:) keyEquivalent:@""];

      [statusMenu addItem:historyItem];

      NSImage *statusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
      [_item setImage:statusImage];
      [_item setMenu:statusMenu];
}

- (void)onHistory:(id)sender {
      OBHistoryWindowController *historyWindowController = [[OBHistoryWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"OBHistoryWindowController"];
      historyWindowController.managedContext = self.managedObjectContext;
      [historyWindowController showWindow];
}
```

OBHistoryWindowController.m

```
- (void)showWindow {
      [NSApp runModalForWindow:self.window];
}
```

I'm guessing I need to somehow on close of the window give focus back to the menu but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't stopped the modal loop.  As the docs for `runModalForWindow:` say, "You can exit the modal loop by calling the `stopModal`, `stopModalWithCode:`, or `abortModal` methods from your modal window code."